# unmarshalling nillable double values

Tags: java, apache, jaxb, jax-ws

I have two fields in class:

```
@XmlElement(nillable=true)
protected Integer roomNumberTo;
@XmlElement(nillable=true, type = Double.class)
protected Double sizeFrom;
```

both fields are optional. Problem I am facing is integer field can accept null values but double can not.

<urn:sizeFrom> </urn:sizeFrom> //it always requires a value.

<urn:roomNumberFrom> </urn:roomNumberFrom> //

if above request is submited I get an Unmarshalling Error:
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:881)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:702)

Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: 
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.NumberFormatException: ]

Comment: Are you sure Integer can accept it? It's possible that because Double is failing first you don't even realize that Integer will also fail if Double is not there.

Comment: yes Integer works. (e.g)  This request works 
<urn:sizeFrom> 55 </urn:sizeFrom>
<urn:roomNumberFrom> </urn:roomNumberFrom>

Answer (score 0):

As tinker already pointed out, the reason `<urn:roomNumberFrom></urn:roomNumberFrom>` is not failing, is that it's simply an unknown element and not mapped to the roomNumberTo field.

If you use JAXB to declare an XML element nillable with `@XmlElement(nillable=true)`, an empty element does not represent the null value. If you map the XML Schema namespace to the 'xsi' prefix, you can declare null value like this:

```
<urn:sizeFrom xsi:nil='true' />
```

Comment: I solved it at the end by using a xml adapter (@XmlJavaTypeAdapter)

 @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=Double.class, value=DoubleXmlAdapter.class)

Comment: public class DoubleXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Double>{
  
public String marshal(Double doubleValue) throws Exception {    
` if (doubleValue != null)   return doubleValue.toString(); 
else null `   }